# How to create a dynamic variable name in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I have a superlist such as :

```
set superlist {{1 2 3} {4 5 6} {7 8 9} {10 11 12} ...}
```

But I do not know in advance that how many sublists I will have in superlist. Is there anyway to create sublists such as :

```
list1 {1 2 3}
list2 {4 5 6}
list3 {7 8 9}
...
```

I think I have to create variable list name according to number of sublists in superlist. Can someone help me with this issue, i.e how to crate variable name while executing the code?

Comment: Is this needed, actually: Why not access the sublists using `lindex $superlist 0`, `lindex $superlist 1`, ... when needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* do this:

```
foreach sublist $superlist {
    set list[incr index] $sublist
}
```

## But don't!

In practice you'll almost certainly be happier with **arrays**.

```
foreach sublist $superlist {
    set list([incr index]) $sublist
}
```

The reason for this is the syntax for access with a variable index:

```
for {set index 1} {$index <= 3} {incr index} {
    puts "at $index is the list $list($index)"
}
```

If you do it the other way, you have to use something rather more awkward like a single-argument `set`.

```
for {set index 1} {$index <= 3} {incr index} {
    puts "at $index is the list [set list$index]"
}
```

(That's the best way of reading from a variable-named variable BTW.)

Comment: Sir it works really fine and the way you elaborate your answers, its really helpful for beginners like me.